# How to get tabs in angular forms based on given xml file?

Tags: angularjs, xml

I have to get number of input tabs or fields based on given xml or json file.

example : If xml has 3 tags, then form should contain 3 input fields.
Same with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat` on service response array of objects. And also you can create new scope variable & assign unique property of response array object to it. Then you can have as many number of input fields based on service data & also dynamic ng-model on them to handle their model data to submit it.
This is small example which demonstrates your requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/

For xml response, better use xml to json library plugins to convert it to json data https://github.com/abdmob/x2js. Or prefer server side sending json data (with implementing xml to json functionality at server side).